# How do I write a class for lines using *args and **kwargs?

Tags: python

Here's my code, with the "#TODO" being the sections I'm stuck on right now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

abscissa = np.arange(20)
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle('color', ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black'])

class MyLine:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #TODO: Implement function


    def draw(self):
        plt.plot(abscissa,self.line(abscissa))

    def get_line(self):
        return "y = {0:.2f}x + {1:.2f}".format(self.slope, self.intercept)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_line()

    def __mul__(self,other):
        #TODO: Implement function


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x1 = MyLine((0,0), (5,5),options = "2pts")
    x1.draw()
    x2 = MyLine((5,0),-1/4, options = "point-slope")
    x2.draw()
    x3 = MyLine("(-4/5)*x + 5", options = "lambda")
    x3.draw()
    x4 = MyLine("x + 2", options = "lambda")
    x4.draw()

    print("The intersection of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(x1,x2,x1*x2))
    print("The intersection of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(x1,x3,x1*x3))
    print("The intersection of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(x1,x4,x1*x4))


    plt.legend([x1.get_line(), x2.get_line(), x3.get_line(), x4.get_line()], loc='upper 
left')
    plt.show()
```

At a minimum, the class should have three instance variables (slope, intercept, and line = lambda x: f(x)), but I'm just having some trouble figuring out how to implement the **init** function with these formal parameters. This is for a class assignment, but I'm not getting much help from peers or my professor and just want some guidance on where to go from here. Thank you so much!

Comment: [*args and **kwargs](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html)

Answer (score 0):

*args gives you a list of the arguments that were passed in. If you have a function `function(1, 2, "stuff")`, you will find `args = [1, 2, "stuff"]`.

**kwargs gives you a dictionary of the *keyword* arguments that were passed in; that is, those with names. So if you pass into a function `function(x='foo', y='bar')`, you will find `kwargs = {x: 'foo', y: 'bar'}.

Here's a nice [page with more tips](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html) about that.

Comment: The *args part makes sense to me. I'm just having a hard time figuring out how the option = "(...)", which I assume is the input for **kwargs, translates to writing this __init__ function.

Comment: Right. Then within __init__, if you do `print(kwargs)`, you'll see `{'option': <your-argument}`.

Answer (score 0):

Which of these 3 params are mandatory? *args (a list of parameter values) and **kwargs (a dictionary of parameter name and value pairs) params usually denote optional parameters.

if all of the parameters are mandatory, i would suggest implementing it in a normal way:

```
def __init__(self, line, slope, intercept):
    self.line = line
    self.slope = slope
    self.intercept = intercept
```

If you HAVE to use *args and **kwargs, you can do it in the following way

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.line = kwargs.get('line')
    self.slope = kwargs.get('slope')
    self.intercept = kwargs.get('intercept')
```

or

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.line = args[0]
    self.slope = args[1]
    self.intercept = args[2]
```

Note that args would expect you to pass the parameters in the "correct" order, but the function definition would not document that order or warn you about it in any way. 
Thus it is best to use *args when you don't need to care about the order in which the parameters are received by the function. Otherwise, other ways are much more safer.